# Go JSON Unmarshalling: Ignoring null fields

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling, decoding

Say I have this code:

```
type TestStruct struct {
    A *string  `json:"a"`
    B *string  `json:"b"`
}

var jsonStr string = `
{
  "a": "a-string",
  "b": null
}
`

aval := "a-default"
bval := "b-default"

foo := TestStruct{
    A: &aval,
    B: &bval,
}

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &foo); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(foo.A)
fmt.Println(foo.B)
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/hmGct_3-2lc)

This will print out:

> 0x{address of A}

> nil

i.e. the "null" value in the JSON will overwrite the value that is in already in the struct prior to unmarshaling. Is there any way in Go to prevent this, and have the decoder ignore any null JSON fields?

I'm trying to find some way to have a struct with pointer fields that have default values (the values in the struct prior to unmarshaling), and that can't be overridden with nulls. Specifically, I need it to be a field that is a pointer, and can have either the default pre-unmarshaling value, or a valid value from the JSON, but never `nil`.

Comment: Note that if you omit the `b` field in the input JSON, it will not overwrite the default value. A field with null value is different from a field that does not exist.

Comment: I know, but the issue is that this is for a REST endpoint so I can't control what JSON the user sends in the request body. I just need to restrict them to either providing a valid value, or it using the default value.